# How to properly import JS and CSS files in Webpacker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I installed Webpacker gem into my Rails app and have difficulties to import JS and CSS files from assets folder to app/javascript/packs folder.

I'm mentioning that app/javascript/packs/application.js looks like this:

```
/* eslint no-console:0 */
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//
// To reference this file, add <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %> to the appropriate
// layout file, like app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
```

and it works properly(in console I get this "Hello World.." text.)

I tried to copy, for example *jquery.slimmenu.js* into *packs* folder and to include it like this:

```
//= require jquery.slimmenu.js
```

but it's not finding in console, there is just application.js and bunch of 404 not find JS and CSS files

Answer (score 0):

your main.js file can be in any directory in app/javascript
for example, create app/javascript/components
then add in your application.js

```
import 'jquery'
require("../components/main");
```

then in your HTML add

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

and script from application.js must be loaded